# Why do i get a Circular Dependency Exception with these Zend_Application_Resources?

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine

I keep getting the following exception with a new resource Im making and i cant figure out why:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Exception' with message 'Circular resource dependency detected' in /opt/local/lib/php/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php:656
Stack trace:
#0 /opt/local/lib/php/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(623): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_executeResource('modules')
#1 /opt/local/lib/php/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(580): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_bootstrap('modules')
#2 /Library/WebServer/Documents/doctrine-dev/library/APP/Doctrine/Application/Resource/Doctrine.php(36): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->bootstrap('modules')
#3 /opt/local/lib/php/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(708): APP_Doctrine_Application_Resource_Doctrine->__construct(Array)
#4 /opt/local/lib/php/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(349): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_loadPluginResource('doctrine', Array)
#5 /opt/local/lib/php/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstra in /opt/local/lib/php/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php on line 656
```

As you'll see below ive created a Doctrine Resource that should load only in the general application bootstrap. In order to perform its tasks it needs the Modules resource to be bootstraped
so it calls `$this->getBootstrap()->bootstrap('modules')`. the Modules resoure never calls Doctrine though, and this seems to be where i get the circular dependency. Ive tried the code that is currently in the constructor for my Doctrine resource also as part of init directly and that doesnt seem to work either. An even bigger mystery to me though is that if i call `$bootstrap->bootstrap('modules')`
by itself before calling `$bootstrap->bootstrap('doctrine')` it all seems to play nicely. So why is there circular reference issue?

Relevant parts of application.xml

```
<resources>
    <frontController>
        <controllerDirectory><zf:const zf:name="APPLICATION_PATH" />/controllers</controllerDirectory>
        <moduleDirectory><zf:const zf:name="APPLICATION_PATH" />/modules</moduleDirectory>
        <moduleControllerDirectoryName value="controllers" />
    </frontController>
    <modules prefixModuleName="Mod" configFilename="module.xml">
        <enabledModules>
            <default />
            <doctrinetest />
            <cms>
                <myOption value="Test Option Value" />
            </cms>
            <menu somevar="menu" />
            <article somevar="article" />
        </enabledModules>
    </modules>
    <doctrine>
        <connections>
            <default dsn="mysql://#####:#####@localhost/#####">
              <attributes useNativeEnum="1" />
            </default>
        </connections>
        <attributes>
          <autoAccessorOverride value="1" />
          <autoloadTableClasses value="1" />
          <modelLoading value="MODEL_LOADING_PEAR" />
        </attributes>
        <directoryNames>
            <sql value="data/sql" />
            <fixtures value="data/fixtures" />
            <migrations value="data/migrations" />
            <yaml value="configs/schemas" />
            <models value="models" />
        </directoryNames>
    </doctrine>
</resources>
```

Doctrine Resource

```
<?php

class APP_Doctrine_Application_Resource_Doctrine extends Zend_Application_Resource_ResourceAbstract
{
    protected $_manager = null;
    protected $_modules = array();
    protected $_attributes = null;
    protected $_connections = array();
    protected $_defaultConnection = null;
    protected $_directoryNames = null;
    protected $_inflectors = array();



    public function __construct($options = null)
    {

        parent::__construct($options);
        $bootstrap = $this->getBootstrap();       


        $autoloader = $bootstrap->getApplication()->getAutoloader();

        $autoloader->pushAutoloader(array('Doctrine_Core', 'autoload'), 'Doctrine');
        spl_autoload_register(array('Doctrine_Core', 'modelsAutoload'));

        $manager = $this->getManager();
        $manager->setAttribute('bootstrap', $bootstrap);

        // default module uses the application bootstrap unless overridden!
        $modules = array('default' => $bootstrap);

        if(!isset($options['useModules']) || 
          (isset($options['useModules']) && (boolean) $options['useModules']))
        {
            $moduleBootstraps = $bootstrap->bootstrap('modules')->getResource('modules');   
            $modules = array_merge($modules, $moduleBootstraps->getArrayCopy()); 
        }                               

        $this->setModules($modules); // configure the modules
        $this->_loadModels(); // load all the models for Doctrine
    }

    public function init()
    {
        return $this->getManager();
    }

    public function setConnections(array $connections)
    {
        $manager = $this->getManager();

        foreach($connections as $name => $config)
        {
            if(isset($config['dsn']))
            {
              $conn = $manager->connection($config['dsn'], $name);        
            }

            if(isset($config['attributes']) && isset($conn))
            {
              $this->setAttributes($config['attributes'], $conn);    
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function setAttributes(array $attributes, Doctrine_Configurable $object = null)
    {
        if($object === null)
        {
            $object = $this->getManager();
        }

        foreach($attributes as $name => $value)
        {
            $object->setAttribute(
              $this->doctrineConstant($name, 'attr'),
              $this->doctrineConstant($value)
            );
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function setModules(array $modules)
    {
        //$this->_modules = $modules;

        foreach($modules as $name => $bootstrap)
        {
            $this->_modules[$name] = $this->_configureModuleOptions($bootstrap);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function setDirectoryNames(array $directoryNames)
    {
        $this->_directoryNames = $directoryNames;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDirectoryNames()
    {
        return $this->_directoryNames;
    }

    public function getDirectoryName($key)
    {
        if(isset($this->_directoryNames[$key]))
        {
            return $this->_directoryNames[$key];
        }

        return null;
    }

    public function getModuleOptions($module = null)
    {
         if($module === null)
         {
             return $this->_modules;
         }

         if(isset($this->_modules[$module]))
         {
             return $this->_modules[$module];
         }

         return null;
    }

    public function doctrineConstant($value, $prefix = '')
    {  
        if($prefix !== '')
        {
            $prefix .= '_';
        }

        $const = $this->_getConstantInflector()->filter(array(
          'prefix'=>$prefix, 
          'key' => $value
        ));

        $const = constant($const);
        return $const !== null ? $const : $value;
    }

    /**
     * getManager
     * @return Doctrine_Manager
     */
    public function getManager()
    {
        if(!$this->_manager)
        {
            $this->_manager = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance();
        }

        return $this->_manager;
    }

    protected function _getConstantInflector()
    {
        if(!isset($this->_inflectors['constant']))
        {
            $callback = new Zend_Filter_Callback(array('callback'=>'ucfirst'));
            $this->_inflectors['constant'] = new Zend_Filter_Inflector(
              'Doctrine_Core::#prefix#key', 
               array(
                  ':prefix' => array($callback, 'Word_CamelCaseToUnderscore', 'StringToUpper'),
                  ':key' => array('Word_SeparatorToCamelCase', 'Word_CamelCaseToUnderscore', 'StringToUpper')
               ), null, '#');
        }

        return $this->_inflectors['constant'];
    }

    protected function _configureModuleOptions(Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract $bootstrap)
    {
        $coreBootstrapClass = get_class($this->getBootstrap());

        if(get_class($bootstrap) === $coreBootstrapClass)
        {
            // handled differently
            $resourceLoader = $bootstrap->bootstrap('DefaultAutoloader')->getResource('DefaultAutoloader');
            $moduleName = $resourceLoader->getNamespace();
        }
        else
        {
            // handle a module bootstrap
            $resourceLoader = $bootstrap->getResourceLoader();
            $moduleName = $bootstrap->getModuleName();
        }

        $resourceTypes = $resourceLoader->getResourceTypes();
        $modelResource = isset($resourceTypes['model']) 
          ? $resourceTypes['model'] 
          : array('path'=>'models', 'namespace'=>'Model');

        $modulePath = $resourceLoader->getBasePath();

        $classPrefix = $modelResource['namespace'];
        $modelsPath = $modelResource['path'];

        $doctrineOptions = array(
            'generateBaseClasses'=>TRUE,
            'generateTableClasses'=>TRUE,
            'baseClassPrefix'=>'Base_',
            'baseClassesDirectory'=> NULL,
            'baseTableClassName'=>'Doctrine_Table',
            'generateAccessors' => true,
            'classPrefix'=>"{$classPrefix}_",
            'classPrefixFiles'=>FALSE,
            'pearStyle'=>TRUE,
            'suffix'=>'.php',
            'phpDocPackage'=> $moduleName,
            'phpDocSubpackage'=>'Models',
        );

        $doctrineConfig = array(
            'data_fixtures_path' => "$modulePath/{$this->getDirectoryName('fixtures')}",
            'models_path' => "$modelsPath",
            'migrations_path' => "$modulePath/{$this->getDirectoryName('migrations')}",
            'yaml_schema_path' => "$modulePath/{$this->getDirectoryName('yaml')}",
            'sql_path' => "$modulePath/{$this->getDirectoryName('sql')}",
            'generate_models_options' => $doctrineOptions 
        );

        return $doctrineConfig;
    }

    protected function _loadModels()
    {
        $moduleOptions = $this->getModuleOptions();

        foreach($moduleOptions as $module => $options)
        {
            Doctrine_Core::loadModels(
              $options['models_path'], 
              Doctrine_Core::MODEL_LOADING_PEAR, 
              $options['generate_models_options']['classPrefix']
            );
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Modules Resource

```
<?php
class APP_Application_Resource_Modules extends Zend_Application_Resource_Modules
{
    protected $_prefixModuleNames = false;
    protected $_moduleNamePrefix = null;
    protected $_defaultModulePrefix = 'Mod';
    protected $_configFileName = 'module.xml';
    protected $_enabledModules = null;

    public function __construct($options = null)
    {
        if(isset($options['prefixModuleName']))
        {
            if(($prefix = APP_Toolkit::literalize($options['prefixModuleName']))
                !== false)
            {
                $this->_prefixModuleNames = true;
                $this->_moduleNamePrefix = is_string($prefix)
                    ? $prefix
                    : $this->_defaultModulePrefix;
            }
        }

        if(isset($options['configFileName']))
        {
            $this->_configFileName = $options['configFileName'];
        }


        parent::__construct($options);
    }

    protected function _mergeModuleConfigs(array $applicationConfig)
    {
       $cacheManager = $this->_getCacheManager();

        if(isset($applicationConfig['resources']['modules']['enabledModules']))
        {
            $applicationModulesOptions = &$applicationConfig['resources']['modules'];
            $enabledModules = &$applicationModulesOptions['enabledModules'];

            $front = $this->getBootstrap()->getResource('frontcontroller');

            foreach($enabledModules as $moduleName => $moduleOptions)
            {

                // cache testing
                // note cache keys for modules are prefixed if prefix is enabled @see _formatModuleName
                if(!$cacheManager->test('config', $this->_formatModuleName($moduleName)))
                {

                    $configPath = $front->getModuleDirectory($moduleName).'/configs/'.$this->getConfigFilename();

                    if(file_exists($configPath))
                    {
                        if(strpos($configPath, ".xml") === false)
                        {
                            throw new Exception(__CLASS__." is only compatible with XML configuration files.");
                        }

                        $config = new Zend_Config_Xml($configPath);
                        $enabledModules[$moduleName] = array_merge((array) $moduleOptions, $config->toArray());

                        //$this->setOptions($options);
                        $cacheManager->save('config', $enabledModules[$moduleName], $this->_formatModuleName($moduleName));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $options = $cacheManager->load('config', $this->_formatModuleName($moduleName));
                    $enabledModules[$moduleName] = array_merge((array) $enabledModules[$moduleName], $options);
                }
            }
        }

        return $applicationConfig;
    }

    public function init()
    {
        /**
         * @var Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BoostrapAbstract
         */

        $bootstrap = $this->getBootstrap();

        if(!$bootstrap->hasResource('frontController'))
        {
            $bootstrap->bootstrap('frontController');
        }

        $front = $bootstrap->getResource('frontController');

        $applicationConfig = $this->_mergeModuleConfigs($bootstrap->getOptions());
        $bootstrap->setOptions($applicationConfig);

        parent::init();


        return $this->_bootstraps;

    }

    /**
     * Format a module name to the module class prefix
     *
     * @param  string $name
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _formatModuleName($name)
    {

        $name = strtolower($name);
        $name = str_replace(array('-', '.'), ' ', $name);
        $name = ucwords($name);
        $name = str_replace(' ', '', $name);
        $options = $this->getOptions();

        if($this->prefixEnabled())
        {
            $name = $this->getModuleNamePrefix().$name;

        }

        return $name;
    }

    protected function _getCacheManager()
    {
        $bootstrap = $this->getBootstrap();

        if(!$bootstrap->hasResource('cacheManager'))
        {
            $bootstrap->bootstrap('cacheManager');
        }

        return $bootstrap->getResource('cacheManager');
    }

    public function prefixEnabled()
    {
        return $this->_prefixModuleNames;
    }

    public function getModuleNamePrefix()
    {
        return $this->_moduleNamePrefix;
    }

    public function getConfigFilename()
    {
        return $this->_configFileName;
    }

    public function setEnabledModules($modules)
    {
        $this->_enabledModules = (array) $modules;
    }

    public function getEnabledModules($controllerDirectories = null)
    {
        if($controllerDirectories instanceof Zend_Controller_Front)
        {
            $controllerDirectories = $controllerDirectories->getControllerDirectory();
        }

        if(is_array($controllerDirectories))
        {
            $options = $this->getOptions();

            $enabledModules = isset($options['enabledModules'])
                ? (array) $options['enabledModules']
                : array();

            $this->_enabledModules =  array_intersect_key($controllerDirectories, $enabledModules);

        }
        elseif(null !== $controllerDirectories)
        {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Argument must be an instance of
                Zend_Controller_Front or an array mathing the format of the
                return value of Zend_Controller_Front::getControllerDirectory().'
            );
        }

        return $this->_enabledModules;
    }

    public function setPrefixModuleName($value)
    {
       $this->_prefixModuleNames = APP_Toolkit::literalize($value);
    }
}
```

Module Bootstrap Base Class

```
<?php

class APP_Application_Module_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
{
    public function _initResourceLoader()
    {
        $loader = $this->getResourceLoader();
        $loader->addResourceType('actionhelper', 'helpers', 'Action_Helper');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this section of the e-book "Survive the Deep End" might help you : [6.6. Step 5: Fixing ZFExt_Bootstrap](http://www.survivethedeepend.com/zendframeworkbook/en/1.0/standardise.the.bootstrap.class.with.zend.application#zfbook.standardise.the.bootstrap.class.with.zend.application.fixing.zfext.bootstrap) -- it specifically speaks about the error you are getting.

*(I won't quote as there is quite a couple of long paragraphs, but, hopefully, this'll help)*

Comment: Good information there. I ran through and checked the for the conflicts it elaborates on but unless im missing it completely, there isnt one. Ill double check again though... Thanks for the link definitely going in my bookmarks!

Comment: have fun in a zf base project? not bloody likely... the more i use zf-mvc the more i wish i was using Symfony or Agavi ;-)

Comment: Finally tracked it down in a completely unrealted resource (my cache manager). Still not sure why that resource is creating a circular ref but it is. While the article didnt directly help it did put me ont he right path so im marking this as the answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Hu, ok ^^ well, you're welcome ; and thanks to you !  (I would say "have fun", but I already did, and you don't seem to have that much fun... so I won't say it again :-D )